# find the dot product of sub-arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

In numpy, the `numpy.dot()` function can be used to calculate the matrix product of two 2D arrays. I have two 3D arrays X and Y (say), and I'd like to calculate the matrix Z where `Z[i] == numpy.dot(X[i], Y[i])` for all `i`. Is this possible to do non-iteratively?

Comment: Over what axis/axes are you wanting to do the product? For the case where X and Y were both 3x3, what is the size of Z?

Comment: @talonmies If the two 3D arrays are K x L x M and K x M x N, the result should be K x L x N.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d
Z = inner1d(X,Y)
```

For example:

```
X = np.random.normal(size=(10,5))
Y = np.random.normal(size=(10,5))
Z1 = inner1d(X,Y)
Z2 = [np.dot(X[k],Y[k]) for k in range(10)]
print np.allclose(Z1,Z2)
```

returns `True`

**Edit** Correction since I didn't see the 3D part of the question

```
from numpy.core.umath_tests import matrix_multiply
X = np.random.normal(size=(10,5,3))
Y = np.random.normal(size=(10,3,5))
Z1 = matrix_multiply(X,Y)
Z2 = np.array([np.dot(X[k],Y[k]) for k in range(10)])
np.allclose(Z1,Z2)  # <== returns True
```

This works because (as the docstring states), `matrix_multiply`provides

> matrix_multiply(x1, x2[, out]) matrix
>
> multiplication on last two dimensions

Comment: As written, I don't think that works if X and Y are 3D, though.

Comment: @DSM - yeah, missed that originally. I now have the corrected solution.

Comment: The corrected version looks good... thanks! I'm sorry if my initial question was not clear.

Comment: @hass: your question was clear, I just missed it when I read it the first time. Glad I could be of help.